# Is Google plus API still read-only?

Tags: ios, google-plus, readonly

I see everywhere that Google Plus API is readonly, but I saw this app screenshot:

[image]

How did they do then? Even the docs say its read only.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The API is indeed still read-only.  We worked directly with SXSW on this year's mobile app to enable sharing... it's not a feature that is generally available at this time.

Comment: +1 Always good to hear from someone who knows the answer. ;-)

Comment: Will, any word on when it might be? Even in vague terms, like "this year"?

Comment: @covati: nothing to announce right now, not even in vague terms. :)

Comment: @WillNorris This was is 2012.... It is now basically mid 2014...... still read only????

Comment: @Supertecnoboff There's the [Moments API](https://developers.google.com/+/api/latest/moments) as well as the [Pages Partner API](https://developers.google.com/+/api/pages-signup).    I don't think there is a public "write posts/activities directly to the stream" API, as I don't see it listed in the [public API docs](https://developers.google.com/+/api/latest/).  I haven't worked on the G+ team for a year, so I don't know what current plans are.

Comment: @WillNorris I see. Well I had a look at the Moments API, seems interesting. Also I just saw they have a Google Plus iOS SDK for sharing but the down side is that you HAVE to use their stupid UI which is rather annoying..... :( Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

The note at the top of the [REST API documentation page](https://developers.google.com/+/api/) seems to answer both questions at once:

> **Note:** The Google+ API currently provides read-only access to public
>   data. All API calls require either an OAuth 2.0 token or an API key.

Comment: yes i saw that but this app seems to give an option to post to google+. I was wondering how they did it