# How to Upload image to google+ wall?

Tags: objective-c, ios, google-plus

I have to upload photo to Google+ wall and I do not understand how to create this uploading.

What should I use? Google+ API( http://google-api-objectivec-client.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/google-api-objectivec-client-read-only ) (project PlusSample)

Or i should create own HTTP Post request?

I need to upload photo and text to google+ wall.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Your link is not working. Check it out and correct it.

Comment: it is SVN repository link http://google-api-objectivec-client.googlecode.com/svn/trunk

Answer (score 4):

The REST API is read only, so you won't be able to insert any images using it.

You do have a couple alternative options, though. Photos on Google+ are powered by Picasa. You can use the [Picasa Web Album APIs](https://developers.google.com/picasa-web/) to interact with images in a user's photos tab. This won't allow you to insert into the stream, though.

Another option is to share it using the [+1 button](https://developers.google.com/+/plugins/+1button/) or [share link](https://developers.google.com/+/plugins/share/). If your image already has a web representation, for example in an image gallery, you can render them in a web view targeting that URL. Your user can then use the plugin to share that content on Google+ into their stream.

Comment: So i do not undersatnd why it is impossible to write text or image to google+ account. And what mind "REST" API ?

Comment: Oh i saw words REST API, sorry, so i find                           [same question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9806118/is-google-plus-api-still-read-only) and here is using SXSW for posting to google plus.

Comment: I all understood, thanks, this feature is not generally available.